# Castle ActiveRecord - can I use the SQL Server 2008 "time" data type?

Tags: castle-activerecord

I'm working on a project where I need to track times, such as "2:15 PM" without dates.  I'm using Castle ActiveRecord.  Is there a way I can specify using the Castle attributes that I want my field to be a time data type in SQL Server 2008?  And if so, what .NET type would I make the field?  DateTime?

In addition, I may need to attach time zones to these times.  What's the best way to do this using Castle ActiveRecord and SQL Server 2008?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675168.aspx) the time datatype corresponds to a TimeSpan .net type, and the [NHibernate type](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2009/03/11/nhibernate-and-ms-sql-server-2008-date-time-datetime2-and-datetimeoffset.aspx) is "TimeAsTimeSpan". In ActiveRecord you'd use the ColumnType property to define this, see [this example](http://www.castleproject.org/activerecord/faq.html#nhlongtextcolumns).

If you want to include time zones I recommend using DateTimeOffset instead. I don't see how time zones would make sense in a TimeSpan... Or store the timezone in a separate field and do the conversions yourself...

Comment: I'll probably keep the time zones in a separate field, just stored as a varchar based on the .NET name for each time zone.  But for the time itself, I experimented with TimeSpan, but storing it that way doesn't make much sense to me, since TimeSpan is designed around length of time rather than clock time.

Comment: After more experimentation, I did decide to go with `TimeSpan` (converting to `time` data type).  The main hitch was converting back and forth between `TimeSpan` and a time display (like "2:00 PM").  But it seems to work OK if I first call `DateTime.Parse` on the `TimeSpan` string, and then use the "t" format.